# How to pair with a Micro:bit on Debian Linux?

Tags: debian, bluetooth

I have BT4.0 USB stick and I run BlueZ.
Bluetoothctl does this, whatever type of agent I use:

```
[bluetooth]# agent 
DisplayOnly      KeyboardDisplay  NoInputNoOutput  on               
DisplayYesNo     KeyboardOnly     off              
[bluetooth]# agent DisplayYesNo 
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# pair C4:F1:D4:D0:44:06
Attempting to pair with C4:F1:D4:D0:44:06
[CHG] Device C4:F1:D4:D0:44:06 UUIDs:
    00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    e95d93af-251d-470a-a062-fa1922dfa9a8
    e95d93b0-251d-470a-a062-fa1922dfa9a8
[CHG] Device C4:F1:D4:D0:44:06 Paired: yes
Pairing successful
[CHG] Device C4:F1:D4:D0:44:06 Appearance: 0x0200
```

However, I loose connection once the micro:bit goes out of pairing mode and back to normal operation. On the microbit I never see PIN code or pairing succeeded. I am then unable to connect with gatttool.

```
gatttool --adapter=hci0 -b C4:F1:D4:D0:44:06 --interactive
[C4:F1:D4:D0:44:06][LE]> connect
Attempting to connect to C4:F1:D4:D0:44:06
Error: connect error: Connection refused (111)
```

Comment: You also need to trust the device with the trust command.

Comment: I did that in `bluetoothctl`...